# YAML: distinguish two references having the same content

Tags: javascript, python, yaml

In YAML I can use references to copy the content of one node referenced using `&mynode` into multiple places using `*mynode`. In my case, a reference may have content that are identical (say two persons having the same name), but I still want to be able to test if two the content is coming from the same reference. For instance, let's consider this YAML:

```
people:
  - &HarryPotter
    - firstName: Harry
    - lastName: Potter
  - &HermioneGranger
    - firstName: Hermione
    - lastName: Granger
  - &HarryPotterTwin
    - firstName: Harry
    - lastName: Potter

books:
  HarryPotter1:
    - *HarryPotter
    - *HermioneGranger
  HarryPotter2:
    - *HarryPotterTwin
    - *HermioneGranger
```

You can see that the harry potter in the first book is not the same harry potter as the second book since the references are different (`&HarryPotter` vs `&HarryPotterTwin`). So even if they turn out to have the same name, I'd like to be able to test if they are actually the same people. Unfortunately, if I test if the two nodes are equal, I'll see that they are the same:

```
>>> stream = open("a.yml")
>>> data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
>>> data
{'people': [[{'firstName': 'Harry'}, {'lastName': 'Potter'}], [{'firstName': 'Hermione'}, {'lastName': 'Granger'}], [{'firstName': 'Harry'}, {'lastName': 'Potter'}]], 'books': {'HarryPotter1': [[{'firstName': 'Harry'}, {'lastName': 'Potter'}], [{'firstName': 'Hermione'}, {'lastName': 'Granger'}]], 'HarryPotter2': [[{'firstName': 'Harry'}, {'lastName': 'Potter'}], [{'firstName': 'Hermione'}, {'lastName': 'Granger'}]]}}
>>> data["books"]["HarryPotter1"][1] == data["books"]["HarryPotter2"][1]
True
```

So is there a way (say in python, but I'm also interested in other languages like javascript) to check if two nodes populated with a reference are actually pointing to the same node?

Note that I'd like to avoid the need of adding an ID or alike, as the `id` should already be the identifier for me.

Note that another solution could be not to use references at all, and just write the path to the ID of the node. But then it means that we need to resolve manually this ID.

Comment: Why have you spammed javascript and pyhton tags in a question that has naff all to do with either language?

Comment: @JaromandaX because I'm asking how to do that with these languages? (see `So is there a way (say in python, but I'm also interested in other languages like javascript)`) The YAML format definitely provides this information, and it's the role of the library to provide it or not to the user.

Comment: I deeply apologise for my misunderstanding ... honestly sorry